# why when i press this button everything disappears?

Tags: javascript, html

how do i create a button that adds a value to another value, i tried like this but every time i run it it makes everything disappear and I only get the operation

```
      <script>
        var x= 40;
        var y= 40;
         document.write(x);
        </script><br>
        <button onclick="bottone1()" class="butto">+</button>
        <script>
            function bottone1(){
              document.write(x+y)
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: As you can read on [MDN documentation for `document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), "***Note:** Because document.write() writes to the document stream, calling document.write() on a closed (loaded) document automatically calls document.open(), which will clear the document.*". `document.write()` is not the method you need in order to achieve what you want, anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `document.write()` rewrites the whole content of the page, so when you run `document.write('hi')` for example, the only thing that remains in your page would be that hi string.
you can also check the jsfiddle

```html
<script>
        var x= 40;
        var y= 40;
         document.write(x);
        </script><br>
        <button onclick="bottone1()" class="butto">+</button>
        <script>
            function bottone1(){
              document.write('hi')
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If u want add value specific element, you can check this.

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Write example</title>
<script>
    var x = 40;
    var y = 40;
    
    function newContent() {
        var demo_element = document.getElementById('demo')
        demo_element.innerHTML = x
        x = x + y
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="">
    <button onclick="newContent();">Click Me</button>
    <p id="demo">40</p>
</body>

</html>
```